# создание теста на php

Tags: php, юнит-тесты

подскажите, что я сделал не правильно, не выводит результаты теста.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<form action="result.php" method="POST">
<div>
    <p>Сколько будет 2 + 2?</p>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="a">3</label>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="b">4</label>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="c">1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Сколько будет 5 - 2?</p>
    <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="a">3</label> 
    <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="b">2</label>
    <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="c">1</label>
</div>
<button type="submit">Результат</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Второй

```
<?php
   $ot = 0;
   $not = 0;
      if ($_POST[q1] == a){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
      if ($_POST[q2] == a){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Правильных ответов: <?php echo $ot; ?></p>
    <p>Неправильных ответов: <?php echo $not; ?></p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[q1] - q1, q2 и "а" в кавычках -

```
if ($_POST["q1"] == "a"){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
```

Comment: спасибо за советы, но парни...не первый не второй вариант не сработал ((((

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['true'] = 0;
$_SESSION['false'] = 0;
if(isset($_GET['q1'])) $q1 = $_GET['q1'];
if(isset($_GET['q2'])) $q2 = $_GET['q2'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div>
            <p>Сколько будет 2 + 2?</p>
            <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="a">3</label>
            <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="b">4</label>
            <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="c">1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Сколько будет 5 - 2?</p>
            <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="a">3</label>
            <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="b">2</label>
            <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="c">1</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Результат">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if($_GET['button']){
    if($q1 == "b"){
        $_SESSION['true'] = ++$_SESSION['true'];
    }else{
        $_SESSION['false'] = ++$_SESSION['false'];
    }

    if($q2 == "a"){
        $_SESSION['true'] = ++$_SESSION['true'];
    }else{
        $_SESSION['false'] = ++$_SESSION['false'];
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Правильных ответов: <?=$_SESSION['true'];?></p>
<p>Неправильных ответов: <?=$_SESSION['false'];?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот это работает, только если тебе не нужно постоянно перезаписывать количество правильных и неправильных ответов.
Хз почему, но все почему то в $_GET летит

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в коде два тега form, срабатывает тот который первый объявлен, в котором никаких параметров нет. Снеси его.

```
  <?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$ot = 0;
$not = 0;
if ($_POST['q1'] == 'a'){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
if ($_POST['q2'] == 'a'){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Правильных ответов: <?php echo $ot; ?></p>
    <p>Неправильных ответов: <?php echo $not; ?></p>
</body> 
</html>
<?
   } else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<div>
    <p>Сколько будет 2 + 2?</p>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="a">3</label>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="b">4</label>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="c">1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Сколько будет 5 - 2?</p>
    <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="a">3</label> 
    <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="b">2</label>
    <label><input name="q2" type="radio" value="c">1</label>
</div>
<button type="submit">Результат</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php }
```